# Как добавить существующий проект в ASP.NET MVC приложение?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Попробую сформулировать вопрос на простом примере. Есть проект - консольное приложение:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Теперь я хочу использовать класс Student в своем другом проекте - WebApplication (ASP.NET MVC) и для этого:

1. Добавил существующий проект ConsoleApplication в решение WebApplication
2. Добавил ссылку на ConsoleApplication в WebApplication

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс Console.Student должен быть моделью для представления About.cshtml:

```
@model ConsoleApplication.Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
```

Когда добавлял строку *@model ConsoleApplication.Student* VS видел пространство имен Console и ошибок при компиляции не было. Но после вызова функции About() т.е. при попытке отобразить представление About.cshtml появляется ошибка:

> Сообщение об ошибке компилятора: CS0246: Не удалось найти имя типа или
>   пространства имен "ConsoleApplication" (пропущена директива using или
>   ссылка на сборку?)
>
> Ошибка источника:
>   public class _Page_Views_Home_About_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ на англоязычном stackoverflow. К сожалению забыл запомнить ссылку. `@Pavel Mayorov` был близок к ответу - вообщем, необходимо в свойствах добавленного проекта ConsoleApplication указать **"Тип выходных данных" = Библиотека классов**.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что файл ConsoleApplication.exe после компиляции успешно скопировался в папку bin веб-приложения.

Если не скопировался - запустите билд проекта через командную строку в режиме подробного вывода (`c:\путь\к\фреймворку\msbuild.exe WebApplication.csproj /d:diag >log.txt`), чтобы понять, где затык. Попробуйте использовать эту модель где-нибудь в .cs-файле (иногда компилятор "теряет" зависимости если почему-то считает их ненужными).

Если же файл там есть - проверьте, что веб-приложение запущено из нужной папки, а не из устаревшей копии.